# Hex values in one word in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

How do I make Excel 2016 convert hex value in one word (two bytes) into a decimal (0xffff must convert to -1 and not to 65535)?
Thanks

Comment: ...but `FFFF` is *not* -1.  `FFFFFFFFFF` is `-1`.  Can you provide a example of what you're trying to do, and perhaps what you've tried so far?

Comment: Open usual Windows calculator (calc command). Choose mode programmer and decimal values. Put in -1. Now the translation into hex depends on what you choose in the menu: BYTE, WORD, DWORD, QWORD:  FF, FFFF, FFFFFFFF, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
In other words, the representation of -1 in hex depends on how many bytes you set for the number. It will be always all FF but with a different length. 
The similar is true for -2 and almost all another negative number.
My original question answered already, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your 16-bit (2-byte) hex value (e.g. "FFFF") in cell A1, you could do this:

```
=BITXOR(HEX2DEC(A1),2^15)-2^15
```

This will:

1. Convert the hex value to unsigned decimal (with the intended negative range of numbers starting at 2^15, i.e. above the intended non-negative range).
2. Invert the most significant bit (bit 15) in order to swap the intended non-negative and negative ranges (both ranges are still non-negative at this point, but now the intended negative range is below the intended non-negative range).
3. Shift both ranges down so the intended negative range reaches its final destination below zero, and the intended non-negative range reaches its final destination at zero and above.

Examples: "0" becomes 0, "7FFF" becomes 32767, "8000" becomes -32768, and "FFFF" becomes -1.

Note: If the input value contains garbage (e.g. "0x") before or after the actual hex value, then this garbage must be removed (e.g. by doing MID(A1,3,4)) before calling HEX2DEC.

Comment: Thanks, but I am really surprised that there is no normal way to do it. The easiest way would be just to add to HEX2DEC function another parameter: how many bytes.
After all kudos about flexibility and usefulness of Excel...Great thanks, nevertheless.

Comment: @Levi, I agree it would be nice with direct support for this in Excel, but at least we now have functions like BITXOR which weren't added until Excel 2013. Maybe someday the programmers at Microsoft will add better support for functions related to programming. :-) By the way, feel free to accept my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The prefix `0x` (used to indicate hexadecimal notation in [c](/questions/tagged/c)) can simply be dropped.

Then Excel's `HEX2DEC` function can do the conversion.

So if `A1` contained `0x3039`, you could use this formula in `B2` (or where ever) to convert it to decimal:

```
=HEX2DEC(MID(A1,3,99))
```

The `MID` function parameters are saying *"return a string up to 99 characters, starting at the 3rd character of A1."*  (So, drop the first two characters)

...and to make up for your "custom -1 rule", you could add an `IF` statement:

```
=IF(LOWER(A1)="0xffff",-1,HEX2DEC(MID(A1,3,99)))
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**`MID` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
- Office.com : [**`HEX2DEC` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/hex2dec-function-8c8c3155-9f37-45a5-a3ee-ee5379ef106e)
- Wikipedia : **[Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)**
- Office.com : [**`IF` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)